# Problems with authentication system: I'm not able to retrieve authenticated user's data in controllers - -laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt

I made an auth system using jwt and works correctly, but in others controllers (not about authentication) I'm trying to retrieve user's data (as id, mail etc) using Auth::user() helper
but don't take the interested data...
this is an example of controller:

```
class UpdateController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function updateToProfessional(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'services' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','exists:services'],
        ]);

        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->removeRole('Regular User');
        $user->assignRole('Professional');

        return $user;
    }
```

Testing the api on postman it suggested me to install laravl/ui package and add auth::routes in my api.php file I know that this create the route for the auth controller but I've already made them using jwt, how can I solve this?
I'll show my routes

```
Route::post('auth/register', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\RegisterController@action');
Route::post('auth/login', 'App\Http\Controllers\api\auth\LoginController');
Route::POST('auth/login/google', 'App\Http\Controllers\api\auth\LoginController@loginByGoogle');
route::post('auth/logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\api\auth\LogoutController');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::post('auth/update/professional', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UpdateController@updateToProfessional');
    Route::post('auth/update/user', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\UpdateController@updateToUser');
    Route::post('auth/edit/data', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\EditDataController@updateName');
    Route::post('auth/edit/phone/number', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\EditDataController@updatePhoneNumber');
    Route::post('auth/edit/password', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\EditDataController@updatePassword');
    Route::post('auth/forget/password', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@submitForgetPasswordForm');
    Route::post('auth/reset/password', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@submitResetPasswordForm');
    Route::post('create/order', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\CustomerOrderController@create');
    Route::post('update/order', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\CustomerOrderController@update');
    Route::post('delete/order', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\CustomerOrderController@delete');
});
```

Comment: I assume you use jwtauth from tymon? Have you follow the integration instruction correctly? You can to use middleware('jwt.auth') and no need to install laravel/ui if you do not need it. For more info have a go on this docs https://www.avyatech.com/rest-api-with-laravel-8-using-jwt-token/

Comment: @Win I've tryied to change jwt.auth middleware in construct method and in routes (I didn’t add middleware to the kernel) but when I test on postman it return 401 unauthorized

Comment: otherwise have you follow the documentation ? https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/#configure-auth-guard

Comment: @Win yes I followed the doc correctly

Comment: Okay I solved, I missed the token authorization in postman request